# Why is Destroy() executed only once in a loop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Assuming Unity created 10 clones, I wanted to delete only 5 of them, so I used the following method.

```
for(int i=0; i<5l; i++)
{
    Debug.Log("check");
    Destroy(GameObject.Find("coin"));
}
```

However, only one was deleted.

Debug.Log() shows 5 outputs, so the loop seems to be working properly. Why does this happen?

Comment: An exception was thrown?

Comment: The code in your question destroys the same object five times?

Comment: `i` is `Int32`, but you're testing `i < 5l` (an `Int64` value), why?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend not packing as many operations into single statement as humanly possible, but rather do reverse - have one operation per statement (like find and destroy separately) and log information about each operation (like if object you've found actually exist and whether it is destroyed already or not).

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html "The object obj is destroyed immediately after the current Update loop" and "Actual object destruction is always delayed until after the current Update loop, but is always done before rendering."

Comment: The documentation for Find says "This function only returns active GameObjects." so you might try disabling the object.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because

```
Destroy(GameObject.Find("coin"));
```

only destroys the game object specifically named, "coin", which is most likely the game object/prefab your clones are based on, and not the clones themselves because the names of all game objects created with

```
Instantiate();
```

are appended with "(Clone)".